# Python timer with Stop Pause and Continue without using time module

Tags: python, timer, continue

How to create Python timer with Stop, Pause and Continue functions without using "time" module, especially time.sleep() because my programm freezes after this function?
Thank you

To be more specific what i am trying to acchieve , I want to create an inapplication script that counts for how long was the programm opened.
If application was minimized - timer has to pause. In this step, using time.sleep() freezes my application
If application is closed - timer has to stop

Comment: If you care about non-freezing, create another thread or Process

Comment: you mean using threading module?

Comment: You can use `threading` module

Comment: Please be more specific about what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you speak about *freeze* I suppose you use an UI framework such as Tkinter, PyQt or whatever else. I you told what is the one you use, you could get more specific answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've correctly undestood your problem, you want something to count how long the application is opened, and pausing all the time the application is minimized. For that, you do not need to use any `sleep`. You simply react to events, noting the time the event occurs and cumulating open time. In pseudo code, it gives :

- App starts in open mode: cumul = 0, openBeg = now, state = open
- app starts in minimized mode : cumul = 0, state = min
- app is minimized : cumul += now - openBeg, state = min
- app is (re-)opened : openBeg = now, state = open
- app is closed : if state is open: cumul += now - openBeg

For python, now is `time.time()` and state should be managed as a boolean `opened = True` when state is open, `opened = False` when stat is min.

It is simple if the application calls a similar API, it will be much more tricky if you have to hook on the windows application state changes.

Comment: you mean to set time.time() when application starts and after minimizing just to count for how long it was opened till minimizing?

Comment: I thought it was was you wanted, yes.